# error when i choose image from gallery using device but not if using emulator

Tags: android, android-intent

why when i choose image from gallery using my device getting error but if using emulator not?
note * the emulator using api 17, and my device using api 19

and after i get error i tried remove this part code from WC_Activity.java and it's working normally

how i can fix that?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

                // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

                // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
            else
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
```

full code

WC_Activity.java

```
package com.emergency.e_place;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Eggy on 5/3/2016.
 */
public class WC_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String TAG = "DEBUG";
    private ImageSwitcher imageview;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private int ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
    Button b;
    Button Camera;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    String realPath;
    String Latitude;
    String Longitude;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wc);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimpanWC);
        Camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Camera);

        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarWC);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //ambil lokasi dari MainActivity
        Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        Latitude = myIntent.getStringExtra("Latitude"); // will return "FirstKeyValue"
        Longitude= myIntent.getStringExtra("Longitude"); // will return "SecondKeyValue"
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + Longitude);
        //ambil lokasi dari MainActivity

        Button ChooseFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChooseFile);
        ChooseFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        Button Camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Camera);
        Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WC_Activity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        });
                        int response= uploadFile(realPath);
                        System.out.println("RES : " + response);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
        String upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.101/e_place/android/upload_image_wc.php";
        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
            return 0;
        }
        try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            //ubah nama gambar menjadi data dari latitude_longitude
            String namafoto = "/"+Latitude+"_"+Longitude+".";
            String namafile = fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("/")) +namafoto+(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1));

            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", namafile);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ namafile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(WC_Activity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(WC_Activity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(WC_Activity.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, data.getData());

                // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, data.getData());

                // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
            else
                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                Log.d(TAG, "niiih : " + realPath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
                imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 300;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}
```

RealPathUtil.java

```
package com.emergency.e_place;

/**
 * Created by Eggy on 6/6/2016.
 */
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class RealPathUtil {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if(cursor != null){
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index
                = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

logcat

```
06-07 18:37:54.324 5168-5168/com.emergency.e_place E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.emergency.e_place, PID: 5168
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/12513 (has extras) }} to activity {com.emergency.e_place/com.emergency.e_place.WC_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3644)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                         at com.emergency.e_place.WC_Activity.getImageUri(WC_Activity.java:244)
                                                                         at com.emergency.e_place.WC_Activity.onActivityResult(WC_Activity.java:209)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5514)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3597)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3644) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 


                                                                     [ 06-07 18:37:54.334   212:  362 D/         ]
                                                                     RIL_onMultiClientUnsolicitedResponse:


                                                                     [ 06-07 18:37:54.334   212:  362 E/         ]
                                                                     unsupported multiclient unsolicited response code 1009
```

Comment: You can use this [library](https://github.com/anoopmaddasseri/MultiImagePicker) for picking image from gallery with custom UI

Comment: Or see [Intent to Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to pick a photo from the gallery.